# When I run The Junit Test Case in Eclispe I am getting The errr

Tags: java, spring, junit, junit4

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

This is the error I received while running the test Case.

This is the file.

```java
package com.shanu.shopbackend.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import com.shanu.shopbackend.dao.CategoryDAO;
import com.shanu.shopbackend.dto.Category;

public class CategoryTestCases {
    
    private static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;
    private static CategoryDAO categoryDAO;
    private Category category;
    
    
    @BeforeClass
    public static void init(){
        context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.scan("com.shanu.shopbackend");
        context.refresh();
        
        categoryDAO= (CategoryDAO)context.getBean("categoryDAO");
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testAddCategory() {
        category = new Category();
        category.setName("Test Mobile");
        category.setDescription("Mobile Descp");
        category.setImageURL("CAT_2.png");
        assertEquals("Succesfully Added a Category",true,categoryDAO.add(category));
        
    }
}
```

For Certain Test Case, I found that Environment Variable setting is null.

[Junit Test Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiMKa.png)

Answer (score 0):

That error suggests that there is a problem with your Java installation, or at least Eclipse is unable to find it.

You could try adding this to your `eclipse.ini` file. Be sure to update the path to point to your actual Java installation.

```
-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.8\bin\javaw.exe
```

Source: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example